# How can I open multiple links on a webpage and scrape there data?

Tags: python, scrapy

I hope you guys are best with your health and R&D work.

```
import webbrowser
import scrapy
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "forum"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://tribune.com.pk/'], #'https://www.siasat.pk/forum/content.php/', 'http://hamariweb.com/news/', 'https://www.urdupoint.com/pakistan/all-news/']
        for url in urls:
            website = urlopen(url)
            webbrowser.open(website)
            print("HELLO WORLD")
            html = website.read()
            all_links = re.findall('"((http|ftp)s?://.*?)"', html)
            for link in all_links:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse)
            
                        
    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split('/')[-2]
        filename = '%s' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

I want to open a webpage and that webpage contains many other links, I want to open all those and wants Scrapy to scrape all those web pages. Please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: instead of having a list of URLs like you have here, just have it as an argument to the function and then call it recursively on all URLs you find. You should probably also store any URL you have previously visited in order to stop scraping the same page multiple/infinitely many times

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'd tried your approach recently by sending fixed arguments in 
website=urlopen('https://tribune.com.pk/') 
but it's not working. Secondly, in future, I've to give multiple web pages for scraping and fixed arguments will not work.

Comment: @op I haven't used Scrapy, but generally when making a crawler, an easy approach is to have a single function that accepts an URL, fetches the URL and then calls itself recursively on all URLs found on that page. That is extremely easy, but doesn't run in parallel, though that can easily be fixed in a multitude of ways.

In your case that seems to be possible to do by making the list urls a parameter to start_requests, and calling start_requests with every link in the loop where you yield the scrapy.Request. 

Is there any specific reason to use scrapy for this and not just a http-lib?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with monsterindia.com and open page using scrapy, that page contain multiple links. I have scraped all the data in the respective link and also we can do pagination. The following code may useful.

```
    class MonsterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'monster'
        start_urls = ['http://jobsearch.monsterindia.com/searchresult.html?day=1&jbc=22']
        item =  BotItem()
        count = 1

        def parse(self, response):
            for href in response.css('h2.seotitle > a::attr(href)'):
                url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
                yield scrapy.Request(url =url, callback = self.parse_details)

            next_page_url = response.css('ul.pager').xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@althref').extract_first()
            print next_page_url
            if next_page_url:
               nextpage = response.css('ul.pager').xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@onclick').extract_first()
               searchresult_num = nextpage.split("'")[1].strip()
               next_page_url = "http://jobsearch.monsterindia.com/searchresult.html?day=1&n="+searchresult_num
               next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url) 
               print next_page_url
               yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for replying you late, my issue is that I want to scrap this (https://tribune.com.pk/ ) and similar ones. I can't send the next_page_url because I don't know the URL as just you know it on an e-commerce website. These are hidden links, I want to extract this main page as well as the hidden link... like if landing page contains 10 articles, I want 11 scraped documents (10 articles of landing page and 1 main page). I hope you get my point.